Multiple port bindings for the same host V3
I have a Centrifugo image that exposes port 8000 for HTTP APIs and port 10000 for gRPC APIs. I have configured Centrifugo with Traefik, and it works fine for HTTP APIs. However, I don't know how to configure it for gRPC.
My configuration for the Traefik service is
version: '3.3'

services:

  traefik:
    # Use the latest v3.0.x Traefik image available
    image: traefik:v3.0
    ports:
      # Listen on port 80, default for HTTP, necessary to redirect to HTTPS
      - 80:80
      # Listen on port 443, default for HTTPS
      - 443:443
      # Listen on port 10000, for grpc
      - 10000:10000
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          # Make the traefik service run only on the node with this label
          # as the node with it has the volume for the certificates
          - node.labels.traefik-public.traefik-public-certificates == true
      labels:
        # Enable Traefik for this service, to make it available in the public network
        - traefik.enable=true
        # Use the traefik-public network (declared below)
        - traefik.docker.network=traefik-public
        # Use the custom label "traefik.constraint-label=traefik-public"
        # This public Traefik will only use services with this label
        # That way you can add other internal Traefik instances per stack if needed
        - traefik.constraint-label=traefik-public
        # admin-auth middleware with HTTP Basic auth
        # Using the environment variables USERNAME and HASHED_PASSWORD
        - traefik.http.middlewares.admin-auth.basicauth.users=${USERNAME?Variable not set}:${HASHED_PASSWORD?Variable not set}
        # https-redirect middleware to redirect HTTP to HTTPS
        # It can be re-used by other stacks in other Docker Compose files
        - traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https
        - traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.permanent=true
        # traefik-http set up only to use the middleware to redirect to https
        # Uses the environment variable DOMAIN
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-http.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`)
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-http.entrypoints=http
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-http.middlewares=https-redirect
        # traefik-https the actual router using HTTPS
        # Uses the environment variable DOMAIN
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`)
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.entrypoints=https
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.tls=true
        # Use the special Traefik service api@internal with the web UI/Dashboard
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.service=api@internal
        # Use the "le" (Let's Encrypt) resolver created below
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.tls.certresolver=le
        # Enable HTTP Basic auth, using the middleware created above
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.middlewares=admin-auth
        # Define the port inside of the Docker service to use
        - traefik.http.services.traefik-public.loadbalancer.server.port=8080
    volumes:
      # Add Docker as a mounted volume, so that Traefik can read the labels of other services
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      # Mount the volume to store the certificates
      - traefik-public-certificates:/certificates
    command:
      # Enable Docker in Traefik, so that it reads labels from Docker services
      - --providers.docker
      # Add a constraint to only use services with the label "traefik.constraint-label=traefik-public"
      - --providers.docker.constraints=Label(`traefik.constraint-label`, `traefik-public`)
      # Do not expose all Docker services, only the ones explicitly exposed
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      # Enable Docker Swarm mode
      - --providers.swarm.endpoint=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      # Create an entrypoint "http" listening on port 80
      - --entrypoints.http.address=:80
      # Create an entrypoint "https" listening on port 443
      - --entrypoints.https.address=:443
      # create an entrypoint "grpc" listening on port 10000
      - --entrypoints.grpc.address=:10000
      # Create the certificate resolver "le" for Let's Encrypt, uses the environment variable EMAIL
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.email=${EMAIL?Variable not set}
      # Store the Let's Encrypt certificates in the mounted volume
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.storage=/certificates/acme.json
      # Use the TLS Challenge for Let's Encrypt
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.tlschallenge=true
      # Enable the access log, with HTTP requests
      - --accesslog
      # Enable the Traefik log, for configurations and errors
      - --log
      # Enable the Dashboard and API
      - --api
    networks:
      # Use the public network created to be shared between Traefik and
      # any other service that needs to be publicly available with HTTPS
      - traefik-public

volumes:
  # Create a volume to store the certificates, there is a constraint to make sure
  # Traefik is always deployed to the same Docker node with the same volume containing
  # the HTTPS certificates
  traefik-public-certificates:

networks:
  # Use the previously created public network "traefik-public", shared with other
  # services that need to be publicly available via this Traefik
  traefik-public:
    external: true


My configuration for the centrifugo service is

centrifugo-service:
    image: centrifugo/centrifugo:v5
    container_name: centrifugo-service
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
      - 20000:10000
    volumes:
      - centrifugo_data:/centrifugo
    command: centrifugo -c config.json  
    ulimits:
      nofile:
        soft: 65535
        hard: 65535
    networks:
      - "traefik-public" 
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      labels:
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.docker.network=traefik-public
        - traefik.constraint-label=traefik-public
        - traefik.http.routers.centrifugo_service_http.rule=Host(`my.domain.com`)
        - traefik.http.routers.centrifugo_service_http.entrypoints=http
        - traefik.http.routers.centrifugo_service_http.middlewares=https-redirect
        - traefik.http.routers.centrifugo_service_https.rule=Host(`my.domain.com`)
        - traefik.http.routers.centrifugo_service_https.entrypoints=https
        - traefik.http.routers.centrifugo_service_https.tls=true
        - traefik.http.routers.centrifugo_service_https.tls.certresolver=le
        - traefik.http.services.centrifugo_service.loadbalancer.server.port=8000


I tried to change the Traefik configuration for the Centrifugo service, but it is not working for me

labels:
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.docker.network=traefik-public
        - traefik.constraint-label=traefik-public
        - traefik.http.routers.centrifugo_service_http.rule=Host(`my.domain.com`)
        - traefik.http.routers.centrifugo_service_http.entrypoints=http
        - traefik.http.routers.centrifugo_service_http.middlewares=https-redirect
        - traefik.http.routers.centrifugo_service_https.rule=Host(`my.domain.com`)
        - traefik.http.routers.centrifugo_service_https.entrypoints=https
        - traefik.http.routers.centrifugo_service_https.tls=true
        - traefik.http.routers.centrifugo_service_https.tls.certresolver=le
        - traefik.http.services.centrifugo_service.loadbalancer.server.port=8000
           ...
        - traefik.http.routers.centrifugo_service_grpc.rule=Host(`my.domain.com`)
        - traefik.http.routers.centrifugo_service_grpc.entrypoints=grpc
        - traefik.http.services.centrifugo_service_grpc.loadbalancer.server.port=10000


Any thoughts on how to map two exposed ports?
Note : I'm new to traefik
